# How to create SQL Server 2008 database full backup programmatically in desired folder

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, backup

How to create SQL Server 2008 database full backup programmatically in desired folder with using Microsoft visual studio 2010 c#

Comment: possible dublicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953598/using-backup-database-programatically

Comment: @Bugai13  that is about how to restore. but i have to learn how backup first :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just execute SQL Server [command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

```
 BACKUP DATABASE database_name TO DISK='d:\path\to\backup\file\on\the\server.bak'
```

Comment: And just remember that you can only backup to drives attached to your SQL Server machine (including UNC paths); you cannot back from a server to a local drive on your PC

Comment: so it is this much easy. i will try now :)

Comment: ok i tried and it works great. but 2 questions. can there be any timeout problem because my database is really big ? also is this same with ms sql server management studio right click desired database tasks backup full ?

Comment: 1) probably yes;
and
2) yes, created backup has exactly the same format.

Comment: Hi, does this command also work with SQL Server 2005? Must either SQL Server 2005/2008 have to have any particular components installed (e.g. SMO components)?

Thanks

Comment: To @user606602: [BACKUP statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) it's the part of T-SQL syntax at least since MS SQL 2000. It doesn't require any external components.