# Set database backup file on local machine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

> **POSSIBLE DUPLICATE OF :**
>
> [How to create SQL Server 2008 database full backup programmatically in desired folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466428/how-to-create-sql-server-2008-database-full-backup-programmatically-in-desired-f)

I have a database on my computer (SQL Server 2008 Express).

I need any sample code in C# that I can use to backup the database to a file using Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks..

i'll using this code to connect Database

```
public SqlConnection SqlSaverConn()
    {
        string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\";
        String conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ path +"SMS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you want to learn how to create a backup from SQL Server database ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Backup Database Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953598/using-backup-database-programatically)

Answer (score 4):

Just execute SQL Server command

```
BACKUP DATABASE database_name TO DISK='d:\path\to\backup\file\on\the\server.bak'
```

from your program

> **EDIT**

```
public SqlConnection SqlSaverConn()      
{
      string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\";
      String conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ path +"SMS_DB.mdf;
                        Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True";
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
      try
      {
          con.Open();
          SqlCommand command;
          command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database SMS_DB.mdf to disk ='" + path + "\\" + name, con);
          command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
          MessageBox.Show("Backup Created."); 
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
      }
      return con;
  }
```

Try this peice of code.

Comment: this code is not for connecting to database. this is to create back up of the database. why dont you post some ccode that will let us help you more.

Comment: Im using flowing code to connect database public SqlConnection SqlSaverConn()
    {
        string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\";
        String conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ path +"SMS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        return con;
    }
can i use your SQL Command to set backup using upon type connection

Answer (score 0):

Im using flowing code to connect database

```
public SqlConnection SqlSaverConn()
{
    string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\";
    String conStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ path +"SMS_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    return con;
}
```

can i use your SQL Command to set backup using upon type connection

Answer (score 0):

This what I did and it Worked!

```
private void BackupButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // FILE NAME WITH DATE DISTICNTION
    string fileName = string.Format("SchoolBackup_{0}.bak", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_h_mm_tt"));
    try
    {
        // YOUR SEREVER OR MACHINE NAME
        Server dbServer = new Server (new ServerConnection("DESKTOP"));
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup dbBackup = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup()
        {
            Action = BackupActionType.Database, 
            Database = "School"
        };

        dbBackup.Devices.AddDevice(@backupDirectory() +"\\"+ fileName, DeviceType.File);
        dbBackup.Initialize = true;
        dbBackup.SqlBackupAsync(dbServer);


        MessageBox.Show("Backup", "Backup Completed!");
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
    }
}


// THE DIRECTOTRY YOU WANT TO SAVE IN
public string backupDirectory()
{
    using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        return dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```